# AppCompatActivity.onCreate still called with @NonNull Bundle

Tags: android

I have used this below configuration for `<activty>` at **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|density|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Still activity's onCreate method called with NonNull Bundle on some devices at user end. I'm not understanding how it's happing.

How can I completely disable calling activity's onCreate method with NonNull Bundle?

Comment: Why you don't check if the `Bundle` is not `null`? It will never be `null` when returning.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes, I can check is Bundle null or not. But, unfortunately this is a web browser app depends on WebView. Once android calls onCreate method all browsing pages need to re-render again and user will loss existing web page instances and HTML input fields data. That's why I want to completely prevent android calling this onCreate method in middle of app session, instead of checking for is Bundle null or not :)

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible, sorry.

Device manufacturers can change whatever they want. If they wish to introduce some new undocumented configuration change, they can do so. Even Google has some undocumented configuration changes, such as `fontWeightAdjustment` and `colorMode`.

There are also certain events that trigger [things that look like configuration changes but cannot be blocked by `android:configChanges`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/10/31/android-12-wallpaper-changes-recreate-activities.html).

Using `android:configChanges` as a way to optimize certain scenarios is fine. However, you cannot guarantee that your activity will never be recreated.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the list of all documented Google Android [`R.attr.configChanges`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#configChanges); `fontWeightAdjustment` is on the list. What ultimately counts is this one `enum` in [`include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h#1017), which indeed may vary from device to device, assuming special hardware which may cause config changes. If you want to know any possible config change, BroadcastReceiver &               IntentFilter for [`Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED) and log to Crashlytics.

But as stated, the `Bundle savedinstanceState` will never be `null` when returning ...
better wrap the code insde `if (savedInstanceSate == null) {}` and call it a day.

One just has to determine which code is fine to run once and which has to run every time
Trying to prevent the `Activity` life-cycle doesn't help, but one may have to deal with it.